# Search window for the program

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

[image]Ruby 1.9.1 Rails 3.1

It seems that I'm stuck on some minor issue, but I'm stuck nevertheless. I'm trying to create the search field on every page of the program and then present the search results in a separate page.

I've edited the layout file to show the search field and it shows on every page. Here is the code that I used:

```
 <%= form_tag("/find", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search RF Club:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:search_string) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

The idea was to use the text, provided in the search field as a variable to pass it later to the view. (Hence the line - text_field_tag(:search_string) )

It seems to be working, as when it goes to the view page the following is displayed if I search for Kirk:
"Client workout listings for Kirk"
I assume it is working the way it is describe because the view file has the line

```
 Client workout listings for <%= params[:search_string] %>
```

The other part of the view file works as well and create the table headers

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Trainer</th>
    <th>Duration mins</th>
    <th>Date of workout</th>
    <th>Paid amount</th>
  </tr>
```

Here comes the problem - even though the "Kirk" string is passed to the page the second part of the page is not working - the one that is supposed to actually present the HTML results of the search query, it simply shows  blank part.
The code that I'm trying to use to present it is:

```
 <% for client_workout in @client_workouts %>
    <tr>
    <td><%=h client_workout.trainer %></td>
    <td><%=h client_workout.duration_mins %></td>
    <td><%=h client_workout.date_of_workout %></td>
    <td><%=h client_workout.paid_amount %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', client_workout %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_client_workout_path(client_workout) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', client_workout, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: delete %>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
```

Any ideas what's wrong here?

---

Controller

```
def find
      @client_workouts=ClientWorkout.find_all_by_client_name(params[:search_string])
end
```

Webrick Console

```
Started GET "/find?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search_string=Kirk&commit=Search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-18 19:19:11 -0500
  Processing by ClientWorkoutsController#find as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "search_string"=>"Kirk", "commit"=>"Search"}
  ←[1m←[36mClientWorkout Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "client_workouts".* FROM "client_workouts" WHERE "client_workouts"
."client_name" = 'Kirk'←[0m
Rendered client_workouts/find.html.erb within layouts/client_workouts (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 90ms (Views: 78.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

Comment: Is that what you actually have in your controller's `find` action? It does not look syntactically correct.

Comment: You have an unterminated `if` statement. Inline `if` statements typically look like `if condition then statement end`.

Comment: crap, it's nit the way it is in my controller file, "if" is just a remnant from the old code. Ive edited the post and removed if.

Comment: Do you have any client_workouts where client_name is "Kirk"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - I'm quite a newbe. (But Kirk is not present anywhere in the file code, except the entry in the database that lists him as a client - it was used as a search string)

Comment: How does your find.html.erb look like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the code you want to render is in `client_workouts/find.html.erb`, then it seems to me that your code is in working order.

My first guess is that your query is simply not returning any results. Can you confirm that you have one or more client workouts where client_name equals Kirk?

You can do this by writing into your Rails console:

```
%> rails c
rails> ClientWorkout.where(:client_name => "Kirk")
```

If this does return results, then my next guess is that your view used to render your client workouts is not being rendered. Is all the ERB you want rendered in find.html.erb?

Max

Comment: Here is the output: irb(main):001:0> ClientWorkout.where(:client_name => "Kirk")
  ←[1m←[36mClientWorkout Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "client_workouts".* FROM "client_workouts" WHERE "client_workouts"
."client_name" = 'Kirk'←[0m
=> []

Comment: "Can you confirm that you have one or more client workouts where client_name equals Kirk?"         ***************       I've uploaded the image to initial post that shows how the index page looks like, soit shows that there is a database entry for Kirk Stigwood

Comment: It's working now - since I'm a new you have to assume that I can do extremely stupid things :) When I search for 'Kirk' nothing is displayed, but when I search for 'Kirk Stigwood' (exactly as it appears in the database) everything is displayed correctly. Same with Lenny Goldberg - 'Lenny' shows nothing, Lenny Goldberg shiw the page populated with query results. OK, but I don't understand why it works like this - I was under impression that every search will look for EVERY match in the db, it doesn't have to be the exact match...

Comment: It does have to be an exact match. If you do a MySQL query using the `=` operator, it will restrict results to exact matches. If you want partial matches for text fields, you'll want to use the `LIKE` operator.